# How can I dynamically assign the options of a lightning combobox based on the input of a lightning input?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, data

I have a lightning combobox (sizeCode) that I want to display the size codes for a product based on the model number that is input in a separate field.

Apex class is working to return an object filled with the size and color values for the model number entered. Example: DEBUG|ProductFilterWrapper:[baseColorCodeList=(BLACK, ORANGE, WHITE, BLUE, PURPLE, PINK), error=null, integrationError=null, sizeCodeList=(M, S, L, XL, XS)].

How can I pull those values into my LWC component and display them in my combobox?

HTML:

```
Combobox:
<div>
    <lightning-accordion class="slds-accordion" active-section-name=[] onsectiontoggle={handleAccordionToggle} allow-multiple-sections-open="true">
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Advanced Search">
            <p>Enter a Model Number to use advanced search.</p>
            <div class="slds-col_padded" style="display: flex">
                <lightning-combobox class="slds-combobox colorCode" variant="label-stacked" name="colorCode" label="Base Color" disabled data-my-id="colorCode">

                </lightning-combobox>

                <lightning-combobox class="slds-combobox sizeCode" variant="label-stacked" name="sizeCode" options={sizeOptions} label="Size Code" disabled data-my-id="sizeCode">

                </lightning-combobox>
            </div>

        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
</div>
```

Input Field:

```
<div class="slds-col_padded slds-size_1-of-2 modelNumber">
    <lightning-input label="Model Number" data-id ="modelnumber" variant="label-stacked" name="ModelNumber__c"
                     pattern="^[0-9]+$"
                     message-when-pattern-mismatch="Only numbers allowed."
                     class="customInputField"
                     onchange={handleModelNumberChange}></lightning-input>
</div>
```

APEX Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ProductFilterWrapper getColorAndSizeCodes(Decimal modelNumber){
    List<String> baseColorList = new List<String>();
    Set<String> baseColorSet = new Set<String>();

    List<String> sizeCodeList = new List<String>();
    Set<String> sizeCodeSet = new Set<String>();
    ProductFilterWrapper additionalProductFilters = new ProductFilterWrapper();
    try{
        String query = 'SELECT Id, BaseColorCode__c, SizeCode__c FROM Product__x ' +
                'WHERE ModelNumber__c = ' + modelNumber + ' LIMIT 2000';
        List<Product__x> productList = Database.query(query);

        for(Product__x product : productList){
            baseColorSet.add(product.BaseColorCode__c);
            sizeCodeSet.add(product.SizeCode__c);
        }
        baseColorList.addAll(baseColorSet);
        sizeCodeList.addAll(sizeCodeSet);
        additionalProductFilters.baseColorCodeList = baseColorList;
        additionalProductFilters.sizeCodeList = sizeCodeList;
    } catch (Exception error){
        Integration_Error__c ie = createIntegrationError(error);
        additionalProductFilters.integrationError = trac_Constants.ERROR_TYPE_PRODUCT_FILTER_ERROR + ie.Id;
        additionalProductFilters.error = true;
    }

    return additionalProductFilters;
}


public class ProductFilterWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> baseColorCodeList;
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<String> sizeCodeList;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String integrationError;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean error;
}
```

JS:

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/trac_ProductSearchController.getProductList';
import getColorAndSizeCodes from '@salesforce/apex/trac_ProductSearchController.getColorAndSizeCodes';
import {getDataConnectorSourceFields} from "lightning/analyticsWaveApi";
import createCaseProducts from '@salesforce/apex/trac_ProductSearchController.createCaseProducts';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const LIMITSIZE = 2000;
const columns = [
 {
 label: 'Model Name', fieldName: 'ModelNameUrl', type:'url',
 typeAttributes: {
 label: {
 fieldName: 'ModelName__c'
 },
 target : '_blank'
 },
 wrapText: true, hideDefaultActions: true
 },
 {label: 'Model #', fieldName: 'ModelNumber__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Wo #', fieldName: 'WoNumber__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Po #', fieldName: 'PoNumber__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Size Code', fieldName: 'SizeCode__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Col Name', fieldName: 'ColorName__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Col Code', fieldName: 'BaseColorCode__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
 {label: 'Price Year', fieldName: 'PriceYear__c', type: 'text', hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText: true},
];

const fieldType = {
 WoNumber__c : 'Number',
 PoNumber__c : 'Number',
 Sku__c : 'Number',
 ModelName__c : 'text',
 SizeCode__c: 'text',
 BaseColorCode__c: 'text',
 PriceYear__c: 'Number',
 ColorName__c: 'text',
 ModelNumber__c : 'Number'
};

export default class ProductSearch extends LightningElement {

 @api recordId;
 modelNumber = 16708;
 sizeOptions = [];
 // @track l_Options;
 fieldMap = new Map();
 rowOffSet = 0;
 products = [];
 error;
 errorMessage = '';
 searchResultsErrorMessage='';
 filter = '';
 columns = columns;
 totalRowCount = 0;
 noRowsSelected = true;
 showSpinner = false;
 a_Record_URL;
 dataLimitMessage ='';


 get options() {
 return [
 {label: 'Apparel', value: 'Apparel'},
 {label: 'Footwear', value: 'Footwear'}
 ];
 }

//{error, data}
 get sizeOptions() {

 return [getColorAndSizeCodes({modelNumber: this.modelNumber})
 .then((result =>{
 for(var i = 0; result.length; i++){
 this.sizeOptions.push({label: result[i].sizeCodeOptions, value:result[i].sizeCodeOptions});
 }
 }))
 .catch((error => {
 this.error = error;
 this.sizeOptions = undefined;
 }))];

 }

 get baseColorOptions(){

 }

 handleFieldChange(event) {
 if (this.fieldMap.has(event.target.name) && (event.target.value === '' || event.target.value === null)) {
 this.fieldMap.delete(event.target.name);
 } else {
 let fieldValue = event.target.value;
 this.fieldMap.set(event.target.name, fieldValue);
 }
 }

 handleModelNumberChange(event){
 this.handleFieldChange(event);
 let colorBox = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-combobox[data-my-id=colorCode]");
 let sizeBox = this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-combobox[data-my-id=sizeCode]");
 if(event.detail.value != ''){
 colorBox.forEach(element=>{
 element.disabled = false;
 });
 sizeBox.forEach(element=>{
 element.disabled = false;
 });
 }else{
 colorBox.forEach(element=>{
 element.disabled = true;
 });
 sizeBox.forEach(element=>{
 element.disabled = true;
 });
 }
 }

handleAccordionToggle(event) {
    console.log('Accordion Test')
    console.log(this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-id=modelNumber]"));
    //console.log(getColorAndSizeCodes(this.template.querySelector("lightning-input[data-id=modelNumber]").value));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the apex method **getColorAndSizeCodes** from the change handler of the Model number input field i.e. **handleModelNumberChange**.

**baseColorCodeList** array from the apex response should become the options for your *colorCode* combobox and the **sizeCodeList** array from the apex response will become the options for your *sizeCode* combobox.